# How to switch off eslint?

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier

I inherited a create-react-app and cannot figure out how eslint is setup so I can (temporarily) turn this off. When I run the app I get this error:

```
./src/redux/store.js
      Line 22:  Replace `⏎··rootReducer,⏎··defaultState,⏎··applyMiddleware(...middlewares)⏎` with `rootReducer,·defaultState,·applyMiddleware(...middlewares)`  prettier/prettier

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

There is no vscode extension running either. How can I turn eslint/prettier off?

Comment: [I don't think you can disabled it in CRA without ejecting](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2157). Maybe it would be easier to look up this code and fix the linting error?

Comment: But you don't know how many you have to fix.

Comment: It says line 22 in the `./src/redux/store.js` file. Isn't that the only one?

Comment: Trust me there are a lot

Comment: Find eslint config and turn off prettier.

Comment: Ok suppose I want to fix this, is there an autofix option like with the extension?

Comment: Did you look at your package.json file ? You may have some prettier config setup there.